# What is a time step with reference to a Recurrent Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am fairly new to RNNs and LSTMs but have spent quite some time studying from various resources I could find on the internet. What I gathered was that a time step in a recurrent neural network was the same as a forward pass in a feed forward neural network. But this turned out to be wrong. Then what is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forward pass involves running one data item (e.g. a full sentence) entirely through the network, until the item is fully processed (i.e. we have classification output).

A time step is the portion of a pass in which node inputs are processed into outputs, and then those outputs are fed to the next node -- often feeding back to a prior input.

Comment: So what you are trying to say is basically the activation of the next layer by the previous layer is a time step. Then what is the "length" of a time step ? How can we control it ?

Comment: Right -- that's a good way to describe it.  The "length" is controlled by the topology: what unit of information-time is handled by a perceptron in one input-to-output pass?  I'm used to audio streams parsing the input into clips of differing sizes, each clip being a few milliseconds long and corresponding to one sub-phoneme phonic element.  Text streams often progress one word at a time (with stop words ignored).

Comment: You described how we control the length. But what is the length of a timestep ?

Comment: That control *defines* the length.  The model itself has no inherent sense of external time -- `timestep` *is* the unit of time in this sense.